# The web page loading speed is slow, but can the server resource usage be small?

Tags: spring, performance, web, optimization, next.js

I have a web server configuration that goes as follows:

**CDN - alb - web(nextjs) - alb - API(spring) - DB**

However, the response from a specific API is very slow, causing the web page loading speed to be very slow as well.

I suspected that the server resources allocated for the API were insufficient, but surprisingly, resource usage was only in the 30% range.

This seems odd to me. If a specific URL is slow, I would expect it to be due to limited resources, but even so resource usage (web, API, DB) remains small.

So, I am wondering why the loading speed is slow even when I have enough resources.

Comment: The speed is the speed of the slowest link in the chain. Measure the speed of each link separately and check your assumptions.

Comment: @jurez / Thanks for the advice. Curiously, what I don't understand is that it only uses about 30% of the resources of all the linked servers, but it's slow. If it's slow, shouldn't it use a lot of server resources on either side?

Comment: That's a wrong assumption. You need to understand what is happening in your case, then investigate and check your assumptions with different metrics and tests as necessary. There are a lot of hardware, software and networking components involved in processing a request, and each of them working and interacting with resources and other components in a particular way.

Comment: For example, if your code running on nextjs server is taking a lot of time because it's not properly designed for multithreading, the database will have nothing to do most of the time. In such case it will not help if you use a faster database. And so on.